# CSS Transform rotateY not working properly

Tags: html, css

So, i have three div's called "point", inside it h1 with class "name" and text. I'm trying to make like 3d effect with perspective on h1 tags.
Code:

```css
.point {
  width: 100%;
  perspective: 200px;
  perspective-origin: left;
}

.name {
  width: 500px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 92px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.name:hover {
  font-size: 105px;
}
```

```html
<div class="point">
  <h1 class="name">ПУНКТ 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="point">
  <h1 class="name">ПУНКТ 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="point">
  <h1 class="name">ПУНКТ 3</h1>
</div>
```

But, in browser it looks like this:

[image: current display]

Every new point breaks the transformation for a bit. You can see that every new element it a bit lower or has a different perspective. But every point element has only one perspective property. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the `transform:rotateY` in the `.name:hover` instead of the `.name` like this

```
            .name{
             width: 500px;
             font-weight: bold;
             font-size: 92px;
             transition: transform 0.5s;
             transform-origin: left center;
        }
        .name:hover {
            transform: rotateY(30deg);
        }
```

you can keep the `.point` class the same.
hopes this is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You need move transform: `transform:rotateY(30deg);` to `.name:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Some margin value sets in h1 .name class.

```
.name {
  width: 500px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 92px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the given code each of the point elements has its own perspective set. This means they are drawn the same e.g. if you measure each corresponding letter and how far down from the top horizontal of the element it is they are the same.

However they can to the human eye look different because the human is expecting the same perspective from their point of viewing.

If you want the whole screen to look like the viewer is standing at one point you have to give the whole thing the same perspective point.

This snippet puts that point on the parent of them all which in this example is the body.

```css
body {
  perspective: 200px;
  perspective-origin: left center;
}
.point {
  width: 100%;
}

.name {
  width: 500px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 92px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.name:hover {
  font-size: 105px;
}
```

```html
<div class="point">
  <h1 class="name">ПУНКТ 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="point">
  <h1 class="name">ПУНКТ 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="point">
  <h1 class="name">ПУНКТ 3</h1>
</div>
```